# Higher-order expansions of a gravitationally coupled system by perturbing the metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, perturbation-theory, linearized-theory

Often in the literature (see e.g. page 142 of https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019), when linearising a gravitational system (pure or matter coupled) around Minkowski space, one writes the metric as $g_{mn}=\eta_{mn}+h_{mn}$. The $h_{mn}$ is usually claimed to be some small perturbation to the metric, and the inverse metric to first order is written $g^{mn}=\eta^{mn}-h^{mn}$. This allows us to perform a series expansion on various geometrical objects (such as the curvature, connections etc).

My question is the following: when doing this, are we actually demanding that $g_{mn}=\eta_{mn}+h_{mn}$ holds exactly, and then computing the inverse metric to first order? This interpretation doesn't change anything at first order, but if we want to go to $\textit{higher-order}$ it does. For example, suppose we wish to perform a second-order expansion, then we are faced with (at least) the following two possibilities:

1. We demand $g_{mn}=\eta_{mn}+h_{mn}$ holds to all orders and compute the inverse metric to second order as $g^{mn}=\eta^{mn}-h^{mn}+h^{mk}h_{k}{}^{n}$. This is done in e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9411092v1, see eq. (2.9) and (2.10).
2. As a second order approximation we write the metric as $g_{mn}=\eta_{mn}+h_{mn}+\frac{1}{2}h_{mk}h^{k}{}_{n}$ and compute its inverse to second order  as $g^{mn}=\eta^{mn}-h^{mn}+\frac{1}{2}h^{mk}h_{k}{}^{n}$.

Whether we choose option (1) or (2) has an effect on the explicit forms of higher-order expansions of geometrical objects. Then, for example, if we use scheme (1) to linearise the Einstein-Hilbert action we would arrive at a different quadratic action than if we had used scheme (2) (actually, it turns out not to matter for a flat background, but it would for a generic Ricci-flat background - anyway hopefully you get the point).

Is one scheme more correct than the other? Or is it just that one is more commonly used and is assumed as a general convention when linearising things? Or are the two schemes actually equivalent (to a fixed order), since the formulae in (2) can be obtained by replacing $h_{mn}\rightarrow h_{mn}+\frac{1}{2}h_{mk}h^k{}_{n}$ in (1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there are different ways to set up perturbation theory, depending on what you want to do.

---

If your goal is to solve Einstein's equations perturbatively, then a common approach would be to expand the metric around an exact solution iteratively (let's just suppose it is Minkowski for simplicity)
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h^{(1)}_{\mu\nu}+h^{(2)}_{\mu\nu} + ...
\end{equation}
The reason reason this is useful is because Einstein's equations for the $n$-th order metric perturbation will be a linear equation, sourced by the $1,2,...n-1$ order perturbations (which were previously solved for). (This case was actually not mentioned in your question).

For example, given a source stress energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$, the leading order Einstein equation is
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E} h^{(1)}_{\mu\nu} = T_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{E}$ is the *Lichnerowicz* operator, or you can say $\mathcal{E} h_{\mu\nu}$ linearized Einstein tensor.

The equation for the second order metric perturbation is then
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E} h^{(2)}_{\mu\nu} = t^{(1)}[h^{(1)}]_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
where $t^{(1)}[h^{(1)}]_{\mu\nu}$ is a pseudo-stress energy tensor depending on $h^{(1)}$. Since we have already solved the leading order equation for $h^{(1)}$, the above equation should be thought of as a linear equation to be solved to $h^{(2)}$.

---

However, this is not the only way to set up perturbation theory. For instance, in quantum field theory, it is more common to *define* the metric perturbation as
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
without further splitting $h_{\mu\nu}$ into a first order piece, second order piece, etc (this corresponds to case 1 in your question). Then we can think of $h_{\mu\nu}$ as a field, and we can do QFT perturbation theory using a Lagrangian with cubic and higher order interactions in $h$, which schematically has the form
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} \sim (\partial h)^2 + h (\partial h)^2 + ...
\end{equation}

---

It is much more rare, although mathematically possible, to write an expression for the metric tensor that is actually non-linear in the metric perturbation (this is the case 2 in your question). This tends to increase the complexity since now you have introduced a non-linear equation that needs to be solved to define the metric perturbation. However there are cases where this may be a useful thing to do. For example, one can work with a vielbein $e^a_\mu$, which is related to the metric via
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{ab} e^a_\mu e^b_\nu
\end{equation}
If the vielbein is a natural field to use (for example if you are coupling fermions to gravity), a useful step may be to perturb the vielbein
\begin{equation}
e^a_\mu = \delta^a_\mu + \frac{1}{2} h^a_\mu 
\end{equation}
This leads to a non-linear expression for the metric perturbation
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu} + \frac{1}{4} \eta_{ab} h^a_\mu h^b_\nu
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer. I am indeed working in the vielbein approach, but the same issue props up: Is one to write $\tilde{e}_{a}{}^{m}=e_{a}{}^{m}+h_{a}{}^{b}e_b{}^{m}+\frac{1}{2}h_{a}{}^{b}h_{b}{}^{c}e_c{}^{m}$ or $\tilde{e}_{a}{}^{m}=e_{a}{}^{m}+h_{a}{}^{b}e_b{}^{m}$? From your answer it depends on your intent. But if I want to compare with someone working in the metric-approach, then beyond first order, it's likely our $h_{ab}$ fields are not the same thing. So we would need to compare perturbative schemes and agree on a map between the two.

Comment: I have a question regarding (for example) Weyl transformations though: suppose we have two conformally related metrics, $\tilde{g}_{mn}=e^{-2\sigma} g_{mn}$. We consider $g_{mn}$ to be a background spacetime with which we want to perform a perturbative expansion about. In scheme (1) of the question, we would have $$\tilde{g}_{mn}=g_{mn}+h_{mn}~, \qquad h_{mn}:=\big(e^{-2\sigma}-1\big)g_{mn}~.$$
In scheme (2) we have $$\tilde{g}_{mn}=g_{mn}+h_{mn}+\frac{1}{2}h_m{}^{p}h_{pn}~,\qquad h_{mn}:=-2\sigma g_{mn}~.$$

In what sense is the $h_{mn}$ of scheme (1) considered to be a perturbation ?

Comment: @NormalsNotFar Yes you need to work out the map between the two sets of variables at higher order. I would recommend asking your Weyl transformation question as a second question since it's a good question and comments are not great for extended discussion. The short version is that you can choose any way to set up a perturbative expansion that is convenient.